# Creating a macro with .sh

Tags: bash, macros

so I would like to write a script that will be used in the following way.

```
./MakeMacro 1
```

The basic form of the script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                             
#########################################                                                             
## ${1} will be number of particles #####                                                             
#########################################
cat > runPgun_${1}_new.mac << +EOF

#Lines of code here

+EOF
```

Inside of the file (runPgun_${1}_new.mac) I want to repeat these lines of code ${1} times:

```
/gps/source/add 1
/gps/particle/neutron
```

Where obviously if there was a 'for' loop I could write ".../add 1   ..../add 2 ..../add 3..etc". The input number determines how many times I want those lines added to the code. I cant seem to reason out where to put the loop. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your existing code, I'm making an assumption that your .mac file either will not exist, or (if it does), you want it overwritten.

```
#!/bin/sh
#########################################
## ${1} will be number of particles #####
#########################################

# If file already exists, delete it.
[ -f runPgun_${1}_new.mac ] && rm runPgun_${1}_new.mac

for PARTICLE in $(seq 1 $1); do
echo /gps/source/add $PARTICLE >> runPgun_${1}_new.mac
echo /gps/particle/neutron >> runPgun_${1}_new.mac
done
```

It was unclear to me if neutron should be run after every add, or only after all of the adds. If it should only be run once, move the second echo to after the `done`.

Results:

```
~> ./MakeMacro.sh 5
~> cat runPgun_5_new.mac
/gps/source/add 1
/gps/particle/neutron
/gps/source/add 2
/gps/particle/neutron
/gps/source/add 3
/gps/particle/neutron
/gps/source/add 4
/gps/particle/neutron
/gps/source/add 5
/gps/particle/neutron
```